# Detect a transparent proxy vs actual object reference?

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

Given an object reference, is it possible to programmatically determine if the object was created in the current appdomain or instead is a proxy to an object in another appdomain?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following

```
var isProxy = RemotingServices.IsTransparentProxy(obj);
```

[System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.IsTransparentProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.remotingservices.istransparentproxy.aspx)